# H2 recursive call not recognizing column

Tags: h2, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the below code and the database says that it can't see column `n`.
I have same problem when I use real database tables. But with real table I'm not even aliasing the column.

```
WITH RECURSIVE counter AS (
  SELECT 1 as n

  UNION ALL

  SELECT n + 1 FROM counter WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT * from counter;
```

Following error is given:

```
Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "N" not found; SQL statement:
WITH RECURSIVE counter AS (
    SELECT 1 as n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM counter WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT * from counter [42122-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
```

Comment: This query works fine in Postgres: [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jS3tp43oSRiwCFQ8C4iuzV/0)

Comment: Hmm.. well I added the error it gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTEs are experimental in H2 and have different issues. Actually you don't need them here. In H2 you can use

```sql
SELECT * FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 10);
```

In both PostgreSQL and H2 you can use the PosgtreSQL-specific

```sql
SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10);
```

If you need to change the column name to `N` add a derived column list `T(N)` after the function.

```sql
SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10) T(N);
```

But if you still want to use a CTE, add column name(s) to the `WITH` clause and optionally remove the alias from the constant, if will not be required in that case:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE counter(n) AS (
  SELECT 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT n + 1 FROM counter WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT * from counter;
```

Comment: My example was simplification. I actually have a real table that I need to recursively cover. But thank, that solved it. I just added all the column names to the recursive call. :D

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error. My unit test was failling (using h2 2.1.210).
My conclusion to avoid error like "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "XXXXX" not found" was:

- add the list of your column names after CTE name as "AS" keyword
- don't name your CTE "CTE"

:-)